# I would like to work on a efficient way to find a list of elements in a page having id attribute ( can have any value ) using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I would like to work on a efficient way to find a list of elements in a page having id attribute ( can have any value ) using selenium.

I can do that with for loop using and `getAttribute("id") != null` on each element of a list of **webElements** find using `driver.findElements(By.xpath("//body//*");` But this not time efficient.

If any one can suggest an efficient way, it would be helpful. I am using Java-Selenium.

Comment: All what you asking is to get a list of all the elements on the page having an "id" attribute? This is the only condition?

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all the elements on the web page having an "id" attribute you can do the following:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]");
```

Since XPath to locate element having "id" attribute is simply `//*[@id]`

Comment: How does it differ from the below answer ?

Comment: No actual difference, we just do it in a parallel. Is it a problem?

Comment: No it's not a problem, but kinda same answer for a question.. anyway that's something out of my control

Answer (score 0):

for all the elements with id attributes we can determine them like below :

**xpath :**

```
//*[@id]
```

and store them in a list like this :

```
List<WebElement> allIDsAttribute = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id]");
```

and then iterate this list to get individual web elements like below :

```
for(WebElement ids : allIDsAttribute){
    System.out.println(ids.getAttribute("id"));
}
```